# Apply Submit Button's Formatting for Normal Buttons in CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cakephp

I have a simple requirement that I need to apply "submit" button's formatting in CakePHP to normal buttons. I have tried copying submit button's formatting in **cake.generic.css** (as described below) but it didn't have any effect on the display of the buttons.

**Existing formatting for Submit Buttons** (if modified, screen shows effect immediately)

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 110%;
    width: auto;
}
form .submit input[type=submit]{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;

}
form .submit input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: #aaa;
  border-left: 5px #000 solid;
  padding-left: 15px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Formatting for button that's not working**

```
input[type=button] {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 110%;
    width: auto;
}

form .button input[type=button]{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;

}
form .button input[type=button]:hover {
    background: #aaa;
  border-left: 5px #000 solid;
  padding-left: 15px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Screen shot of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqxTc.jpg)

**edit.ctp code for buttons** (style is working and button's color changed to yellow)

```
echo $this->Form->button('Disable', array('style'=>'background:#FF0', 'type'=>'button','onclick'=> 'change_status(0);'));
        echo "\t";
        echo $this->Form->button('Delete', array('type'=>'button', 'onclick'=> 'change_status(2);'));
```

Now I need to know how to code for "hover" inside style in edit.ctp. I know it's workaround but I am OK with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don´t try use **Link**

```
<?= $this -> Html -> link('Disable', [], array('class' => 'button yourClass', 'onclick' => 'change_status(0);')); ?>
```

And then define yourClassName in css

```
form .button .yourClass{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;

}
form .button .yourClassName:hover {
  background: #aaa;
  border-left: 5px #000 solid;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Formatting didn't have any effect on link either. Maybe there is some other file too that needs to be modified for changes to work?

Comment: Maybe you have a css conflict try adding some `style` to see if it´s works `<?= $this -> Html -> link('Disable', [], ['style' => 'background: #aaa']); ?>`

Comment: Now, custom style is working for the button but I don't know how to apply formatting for hover

Comment: @mnh Edit your question and add new code to see your progress

Comment: Yes I see, if this works `$this -> Form -> button('Disable', array('style' => 'background:#FF0', 'type' => 'button'));` this shoud works too `$this -> Form -> button('Disable', array('class' => 'YOURCLASS', 'type' => 'button'));` check if your page load corectly css files

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jacek B Budzyñski, I have solved the problem. Following code was added to cake.generic.css

```
form .buttonClass{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;

}
form .buttonClass:hover {
  background: #aaa;
  border-left: 5px #000 solid;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Used this code in edit.ctp as given below

```
echo $this->Form->button('Disable', array('type'=>'button', 'class'=>'buttonClass','onclick'=> 'change_status(0);'));
    echo $this->Form->button('Delete', array('type'=>'button', 'class'=>'buttonClass', 'onclick'=> 'change_status(2);'));
```